# how to execute a block of code atomically in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, atomic, dispatcher

I have a multi-threaded UI application that starts numerous background threads.  A lot of these threads execute code that looks as follows:

```
public void Update(){
   if(Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted()) return;
   Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{...});
...
}
```

Then I sometimes may have a thread execute the following code

```
pubic void Shutdown(){
   if(Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted()) return;
   Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
}
```

The problem is that sometimes one thread executes `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()` AFTER another thread executed `Dispatcher.HasShutdwonStarted()` but before it got to `Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{...})`.  Which means, that there will be a thread trying to execute a lambda on the Dispatcher once the Dispatcher has begun to shut down.  And that's when I get exceptions.  What is the best solution to this?

Comment: _"And that's when I get exceptions. "_ like which exceptions?

Comment: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is that the HasShutdownStarted is checked, before the code inside the Invoke is executed (because it's queued on the dispatcher)

I think a better way is to check it **inside** the invoke, this way you don't need any locks.

```
public void Update(){
   Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>
   {
       if(Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted()) return;
       ...
   });
}
```

Comment: If you call invoke from the UI thread it works just fine.  It doesn't deadlock.  It'll just invoke the callback instead of dispatching it to the message loop.

Comment: Like it tried to explane. If you close the window and you dispose (for example) a socket, which invokes a disconnected event (try/catch) on his thread, you'll get a deadlock. UIthread => WindowClose => SocketThread => OnDisconnected => UiThread Invoke.

Comment: The UI thread isn't blocking on anything through.  It just runs the code without waiting on anything, so there is no deadlock.  Well, that's assuming you're not doing really bad things like replacing the current synchronization context on the UI thread before calling a method like this so that the code is on the UI thread but doesn't *realize* it's on the UI thread, but just...don't do that.  If you did, that's the thing to fix, not the use of `Invoke` everywhere in anticipation of people doing things they shouldn't.

Comment: You may not understand what I mean and this will only confuse you. The point is that if the UI thread tries to terminate some other thread (thread.join) and the other thread uses Dispatcher.Invoke you'll get a deadlock. If this is still unclear, i'll remove the example. :'(

Comment: Sure, if the critical section here is waiting on another thread, then that could cause deadlocks.  What gives you any indication it's doing that?  That sounds like something that has no business being in this critical section.  Having a UI thread block until some other thread finishes sounds like a real bad idea even if that other thread never dispatches to the UI thread.  Long running operations shouldn't be run from the UI thread, such as waiting for arbitrary worker threads to finish.  That's the thing that should be asynchronous.

Comment: I'll write an example, maybe you can give a better explanation (if you would like to)

Comment: Again, the problem is *the UI thread shouldn't be waiting on an arbitrary thread to finish running*.  That's the problem in the code, not that the other thread is using `Invoke`.  You should not block the UI thread for arbitrary periods of time.  That will cause problems even if that other thread *doesn't do anything with the UI* because you're now blocking the UI thread for a long time, even if it's not forever.  That's bad.  Your UI needs to be responsive, it should only ever run code that runs very quickly.

Comment: I agree on that... But i've seen it dosens of times. We've all been there (i guess) (at least I)  .  I'll remove the example, if you think it's a bad example

Comment: I mean sure, people write code that they shouldn't.  But that doesn't mean you structure your entire application on the people will do stuff that they shouldn't, and where those changes don't even fix the problem, but rather make it slightly less bad.  When people block the UI thread waiting on a worker thread then you *fix that problem* rather than never using `Invoke` to try to put a band aid on a broken bone.

Comment: True, I'll remove the BeginInvoke stuff. I may have gone too far ahead

Answer (score 1):

With the help of others I managed to come up with the following solution to my problem and thought I'd share it.  Calling `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)` after `Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown()` will always lead to a `TaskCancelationException` being thrown (as far as I can tell).  Thus, checking `Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted` inside of the Invoke method will not work.

What I did was create an application global `CancellationToken` by creating a `static CancellationTokenSource`.  I now invoke the Dispatcher as follows:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{...}, DispatcherPriority.Send, GlobalMembers.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Then, when I wish to invoke shutdown on my dispatcher, I do the following:

```
GlobalMembers.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
```

If by any chance I try to run `Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{...}, DispatcherPriority.Send, GlobalMembers.CancellationTokenSource.Token)` after cancelling the global token and after invoking Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown(), nothing happens as the token is already cancelled and thus the action is not run.