# Changing some Dispatcher.BeginInvoke functionality into that of Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, dispatcher

The reason for what I'm going to ask here is that Dispatcher.Invoke throws a [TaskCanceledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception?view=net-6.0) when another thread executes Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown().  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() does not seem to suffer from this and I wanted to move my codebase from using Dispatcher.Invoke(...) to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...).  And below I wanted to ask if the following two Work() methods both running on a separate background thread are equivalent? (do any of you see any issues changing the first into the second?):

```
Work(){
   Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {sameFunction()});

   //more work
   ...
}

Work(){
   var task = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>  {sameFunction()});
   task.Wait();

   //more work
   ...
}
```

This issue is a direct consequence of the [following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467541/how-to-execute-a-block-of-code-atomically-in-c-sharp/70467718#70467718)'s answer not having functioned as hoped for.  It seems that once Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown has been called (once Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted is true), all calls to Dispatcher.Invoke will end in throwing a [TaskCancelledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception?view=net-6.0).

Comment: You should avoid .wait and instead use await task. And use dispatcher.invokeasync. I wonder what you're doing on the ui thread that must be complete before background processing continues. That seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` instead of `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. `BeginInvoke` is part of the old API.
Also, never call `Wait()`, but use `await`:

```cs
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()
```

Using the new API also allows you to cancel operations (`Invoke` and `InvokeAsync` only): to fix the exception issue, you should provide a shared `CancellationToken`, that you associate with the `Dispatcher` (virtually, with the one you expect to get shutdown), to every invocation.
This way you can cancel the pending and running operations gracefully ***before*** you shutdown the `Dispatcher`.

`Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown` will abort any running `Dispatcher` operation, which applies to every synchronous `Dispatcher.Invoke` execution - hence the `TaskCanceledException` is being thrown on abortion.
Regarding `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` (and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`): your probably don't experience the cancellation exception, because the dispatched operation is still pending due to its asynchronous execution.

This leads to the difference of both `Dispatcher` invocation examples:

Your first example uses `Dispatcher.Invoke`. From the documentation you could learn that it executes *synchronously*. This means, the delegate is executed immediately (pushed to the front of the queue - respecting the assigned priorities).

The second example uses `Dispatcher.BegingInvoke` (same applies to the modern `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`). This method invokes the delegate *asynchronously*. This means, the delegate is enqueued into the dispatcher queue and executed after all preceeding pending operations in this queue are completed. If you don't `await` the call, the `Dispatcher` returns immediately after enqueuing the delegate and execution continues (this is the asynchronous part).

Therfore, the examples are not equivalent. You have to decide if postponing the delegate's execution is reasonable (`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`) or not (`Dispatcher.Invoke`).